# How to reconstruct image/array from list of extracted patches in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image

I have an image size of `256x256`. I will extract the image into patches with a size of `32x32`, and the center of a patch will slide with window step of 20. If extracted patch size is smaller than `32x32`. Then add zero padding to obtain `32x32`. The code to extract patch is

```
import numpy as np
image = np.random.randn(256,256)
patch_H, patch_W = 32, 32
step_H, step_W = 20, 20

lst_H = np.arange(0, image.shape[0] + patch_H, step_H)
lst_W = np.arange(0, image.shape[1] + patch_W, step_W)
image_patches =[]
for i in range(len(lst_H)):
  for j in range(len(lst_W)):
    h= lst_H[i]
    w= lst_W[j]
    patch = image[h : h + patch_H, w : w + patch_W]
    # Zero padding
    if (patch.shape[0]!= patch_H or patch.shape[1]!= patch_W):
      patch = np.pad(patch,[(0, patch_H- patch.shape[0]), (0, patch_W- patch.shape[1])], mode='constant')
    patch =patch[None,:,:]
    image_patches.append(patch)
image_patches = np.vstack(image_patches) # (225, 32, 32)
```

Using the code above, I obtain 225 patches size of `32x32`. From the `image_patches`, I want to generate a new image with the same size as the original image (`256x256`) and the values are summed up between overlapping patches.

The difficult is that I have to unpad the patches that are zero padding in the first step. Thus I cannot assign the `image_rec[h : h + patch_H, w : w + patch_W]+=image_patches[num_patches,:,:]` in bellow code if I did not unpad them. How could I solve the problem? In my opinion, I guess we have to save a dictionary to save the other keys such as zero flag, position...This is what I done

```
# Recover the image
image_rec = np.zeros (image.shape)
num_patches=0
for i in range(len(lst_H)):
  for j in range(len(lst_W)):
    h= lst_H[i]
    w= lst_W[j]
    image_rec[h : h + patch_H, w : w + patch_W]+=image_patches[num_patches,:,:]
    num_patches +=1
```